# How to pass a CURSOR as an Oracle Function parameter from MyBatis

Tags: java, mybatis

We use MyBatis for ORM. I need to call an Oracle Function which takes a cursor as a parameter. It would be ideal if MyBatis could map a Java object to the cursor but I doubt that is possible.

Any ideas how to do that?

Please note that I know how map a cursor returned from a function to a Java object. The other way around is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the only solution is to create a block, declare a cursor and pass it to the function manually:

```
<select id="..." parameterType="..." statementType="CALLABLE">
    declare
          my_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
    begin
          OPEN my_cursor FOR
                    <foreach item="item" collection="..." separator=" union all ">
                    SELECT #{item.key} as key, ... FROM dual
                    </foreach> ;

        #{result,jdbcType=CURSOR,mode=OUT,resultMap=...,javaType=java.sql.ResultSet} := our_function(my_cursor => my_cursor);
    end;
</select>
```